# how to use post method to contoller and phtml for button event in magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, jquery, post-data

> I have a button in phtml file

some.phtml

```
<button class="example-button-1 example-button-3 :active" type="button" id="acceptnow" ><span>Active</span></button>
```

> I want to use post method to the controller for triggering the email
>
> but how I do that???

Comment: You can use AJAX for this.

Comment: how??????????..

Comment: On click get parameters you require and post those to controller.

Comment: here i don't want to redirect the page.....

but i want i like add to cart button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#acceptnow").click(function(e)
{
      var formurl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('Vendor/Extension/Action'); ?>'; 
      jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: formurl,
          data:{variable:variable},
          beforeSend: function()
          {
              //do Logic before ajax request start
          }, 
          success: function(transport) 
          {
              //Do Logic when sucess comes
          },
          error: function() 
          {
              //Do Logic when error into request
          }
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Vendor/Extension/Action      in  here what i can give

Comment: That is the action url of your controller.